# Send webrequest after spliting data in Listbox in ":" format

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

hello i have a listbox which contains different lines but all in user:pass format how can i split them in such a way to to send webrequest for each item in ListBox .
I have tried this but it only send request for the first item in listbox but i want it to send webrequest for all the items in it .

```
For Each item In ListBox1.Items
                Dim z = item.Split(":").GetValue(0)
                Dim zz = item.Split(":").GetValue(1)
 Next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put the webrequest inside the loop and use ,`Dim z() As String = item.Split(":")`.  z(0) is the user and z(1) is the pass and will change with each iteration of the loop.

A suggestion though, a Dictionary(Of String, String) might be a better storage option for the data, since that won't expose it to any straying eyes.

Or even a listview with 2 columns. Using the view option, List, will show only the first column, but the data for the second column is still accessible.

UPDATE:

A dictionary is a collection of Key,Value pairs.  If you want you can think of it in terms of an array.  An array can be described as being a collection of key,value pairs.  The index of the item is the key and the value of the item is the value.  A dictionary works the same way, with the additional flexibility of assigning any type as being the key.  The Dictionary class also includes methods for adding, removing, etc., and is LINQ compliant.

In your example you would make the user the key and the password the value.  then a for each loop would look like this:

```
For Each kv As KeyValuePair In MyDictionary
```

kv.Key is the user and kv.Value is the password.

Here's the MSDN [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/xfhwa508%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) if you want more detailed information.

Comment: Ty it worked :D btw how can i do it with Dictionary as i have never used it before any help would be appreciated :D